# HTTP Request URL changed

Tags: php, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have web service on .NET which is called from other 3rd party service using PHP. My web service has domain name foo.example.com and it's binded to http (redirected using url rewrite to https) and https.

And now, what's the problem is. PHP party call https://foo.example.com/api/controller/method, .NET service handle request and there is bug in code:

```
var serviceUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```

serviceUrl shoul be *https://foo.example.com*, but is *https://www.example.com*

It's strange for me. Can somebody explain where can be problem? From others 3rd party request handled succesfully.

Comment: `it's binded to http (redirected using url rewrite to https)` - how is this set up?

Comment: using url-rewrite module of iis - inbound rule, redirection type 302 Found